# Refreshing users webpage with python / flask

Tags: python, flask

I am creating a thread and after that thread finishes I want to refresh the users page and send him to another page. But I am really new to python and flask so I have no idea how to do that.

This is my code so far:

```
nit = Thread()
def stampa():
    print ("Starting")
    com = "python plan.py"
    proc = subprocess.Popen(com.split(),shell=False)
    if proc.wait()!=0:
        print ("Ne radi")
    else:
        print ("Radi")
        return redirect('ended')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    return render_template("homepage.html")

@app.route('/start_thread', methods=['GET','POST'])
def start_thread():
    global nit
    nit = Thread(target = stampa)
    nit.start()
    return redirect('end')

@app.route('/end', methods=['GET','POST'])
def end():
    global nit
    if nit.is_alive():
        return "Still working"
    else:
        return redirect('ended')
@app.route('/ended', methods=['GET','POST'])
def ended():
    return "It has ended"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

The homepage template has just 1 button that redirects to `start_thread`.
The reason why I start a thread is because I dont want the windows to freeze while the program runs (it takes about 5 minutes to finish). for now the user has to refresh the page manually to see if the process has finished but I want to be able to do it myself.
Does anyone have a solution? ( Or any idea that I can research ?)

Comment: http://www.celeryproject.org/ and https://www.rabbitmq.com/ would be good tools to look at. I think you'll need some javascript on the front end to accomplish what you're looking to do, as far as i'm aware the server can't "push" content to the client without a client initiated request. You could use a `setInterval()` javascript function to periodically check a flask endpoint for progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As stated in the documentation, `wait` can cause deadlock, so communicate is
>   advisable.  [subprocess.html#convenience-functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#convenience-functions)

Please try

```
def stampa():
    print ("Starting")
    com = "python plan.py"
    proc = subprocess.Popen(com.split(),shell=False)
    if proc.wait()!=0:
        print ("Ne radi")
    else:
        print ("Radi")
        return redirect('ended')
```

To

```
def stampa():
    print ("Starting")
    com = "python plan.py"
    proc = subprocess.Popen(com.split(),shell=False)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    exitCode = proc.returncode
    if (exitCode == 0):
        return redirect('ended') # refresh
    else:
        # raise some exception
        pass
```

Comment: @MilosRadosavljevic " for now the user has to refresh the page manually to see if the process has finished but I want to be able to do it myself. "
I thought the idea you want refresh the page automatically after the thread process done?

Comment: I have found the solution, you cant just redirect because you are in a thread. I needed to use javascript and send requests to see if the thread has finished